# How do I detect an empty json respone?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make it detect a sometimes empty json response, which would be [].

```py
if r.json() != None:
    print("Yes Json")
    sleep(1)
    main()
else:
    print("No Json")
    sleep(1)
    main()
```

I've already tried things like

```
if r.json() != "[]":
if r.json() != []:
if r.text != "[]":
if r.text != []:
```

But It always just goes to `print("No Json")`, despite Json not being empty.

I also tried `print(repr(r.json()))`, Which still gave me []

and `print(r.json(), type(r.json()))`, Which gave me [] <class 'list'>

Comment: Is your indentation correct??

Comment: `print(repr(r.json()))` to see what you're actually getting.

Comment: What is the code before ?

Comment: My indentation in the program is correct, and It still responds with [] when empty.

Comment: Please do `print(r.json(), type(r.json()))` and show us

Comment: @azro its just a get request before that

Comment: `if r.json() != []:` should work, try `print(if r.json() == [])` and `if r.json():` only

Comment: something in that fixed it, no idea how but ty @azro

Comment: "something in that fixed it, no idea how" - you may want to find out how else you'll be asking again the next time it happens to you.

Answer (score -1):

You can just use

```py
if r.json():
   # Returns true if json is not empty
```